# Virtual hosts only working for 2/4 directories?

Tags: centos, virtualhost, httpd, httpd.conf

I am running CentOS 6.2 and I have in httpd.conf the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@example.co.uk
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.co.uk/public
    ServerName example.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/example.co.uk-error_log
    CustomLog logs/example.co.uk-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
#user1 directory
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/public_html    
    ServerName user1.example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/user1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
#user2 directory
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /home/user2/public_html
    ServerName user2.example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/user2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
#user3 directory
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@example.co.uk
     DocumentRoot /home/user3/public_html
    ServerName user3.example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/user3-error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Those directories do exist I am able to see main virtual host(`ServerName example.co.uk`) and user2 when I navigate to `http//exmaple.co.uk` and `http://user2.exmaple.co.uk` but not user1 and user3. Can anyone spot any errors?

**UPDATE**
Apche error log:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed May 08 15:45:42 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 08 15:48:02 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 08 15:48:03 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed May 08 15:48:03 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed May 08 15:48:03 2013] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed May 08 15:48:03 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

[image]

Same error over and over again but the user2 subdomain works fine? I have kept the ServerAlia only on the main one pointing to my www folder. Stoll broken? :(

Comment: The error-log for the other two users are blank which makes me suspect when I navigate to their subdomains it's not even hitting their VH directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same ServerAlias on all your vhosts.... Thats definitly an error - we'll see if this is related to your problem.

If it's still not working we need the output from your logs and some information what your browser says.

Comment: Added the erro-log info the browser just displays the the normal chrome oops page (similar to the one pictured) with no headers or console/network errors? :S

Comment: Is your DNS set up correctly? (so - can you resolve the IP adress from your non-working subdomains?)

Comment: I can't think how I would check off the top of my head, how would I resolve the IP?

Comment: ping user1.example.com has to resolve to your servers IP address

Comment: Doh! I was thinking you meant dig or something like that lol
"Ping request could not find host user3 blah blah..." how come user 2 works? :S

Comment: dig should work fine too ;)

Comment: ping user2.example.com - that should be working i think? for details you have to check your nameserver config :)

Comment: The DNS settings are held by 123-reg.com I'll check them, thanks :)